# Understanding why my code for the Two Sum (LeetCode problem) in C# does not work for expected answer of [1,2]

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve the Two Sum LeetCode problem. In this problem, you are given an array of integers named nums and a variable containing an integer named target. The problem is asking to return an array that contains the indices of the two numbers that add up to the target.

For example, you have nums = [2,7,11,15] and target= 9. The expected output would be [0,1] because 2+7 = 9.

My code (which is shown below) works for the above example, however, it doesn't work for the second example that LeetCode checks: nums= [3,2,4], target = [6],  expected outcome is [1,2]

I would like to know why my code isn't working for the second example and how I can modify it so it can work.

Code that I used for this problem:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        //Initializing i, k and sum variables
        int i=0;
        int k= 0;
        int sum= 0;
        
        for(i=0; i<= nums.Length-1 ; i++) 
        {
            

            if(i< nums.Length)
            {
                k= i+1;
            
                sum= nums[i] + nums[k];
                
                if(sum== target)
                {
                    //Returns an array in the compiler containing the values of i and k.
                    return new int[] {i, k};
                } else 
                {
                    return new int[0];
                }
                
                
            } else
            {
                return Array.Empty < int > ();
            }           

        }
        return new int[0]; //Returns an empty array if the solution is not found
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Also, please explain what "doesn't work" means. Does it return incorrect results? Throw an exception?

Comment: As madreflection, mentioned, first step in understanding would be to step through with a debugger. If you're writing in VS studio, set a breakpoint, then look at the step buttons to navigate through the code while it's executing. From first glance, it seems like your code is immediately returning on the first execution of the for loop (you have return statements, throughout so it never makes it to the next iteration of the loop). The reason it worked the first time is because the solution happens to be in the first iteration.

Comment: The two places where you return an empty array from within the loop look suspect. They prohibit that your code searches for more solutions.

Comment: Refer this https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/1-two-sum-fd566d9a79cb. And also you can register here and practice https://www.hackerrank.com/

Comment: moreover ... suppose your array has 5 elements, valid indexes are 0 to 4. In the for loop test you have `i <= nums.Length-1` so the index can become 4. in the branch of for there is an if `i <nums.Length` and also in this case the index (i) can reach 4. But in the branch of this last if you assign` i + 1` to `k`, so in the case of `i = 4` you assign 5 which is not a valid index.

Comment: Hello madreflection, halibut, Klaus Gutter, Avantha Siriwardana and Jak. I placed the code in Visual Studio and saw where the problem was. I removed the Else statement after if(sum== target) and it now works. When I had the Else statement, the compiler in LeetCode would return an empty array instead of [1,2] for the nums array containing [3,2,4] with a target of 6. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I feel like the compiler in LeetCode is confusing me. I know that I need to do LeetCode problems to practice, but I feel like it is easier to take the problems and do them on Visual Studio instead of using their compiler.

Comment: I changed the i<nums.Length to i<nums.Length-1. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, write your code in Visual Studio, paste it in LeetCode to submit. I know nothing about LeetCode, but I assure you, Visual Studio is a much better starting point, and a much better environment overall. You should be learning how to debug just as much as how to write code, and LeetCode clearly wasn't the place for that.

Comment: Also, your `for` loop is not idiomatic. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,, madreflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the else block here

```
        if(sum== target)
        {
            //Returns an array in the compiler containing the values of i and k.
            return new int[] {i, k};
        } else 
        {
            return new int[0];
        }
```

When you don't hit the target with indexes 0 and 1, you return the empty array instead of trying with indexes 1 and 2.

If you delete the else block, your code will work with the example you've given.

Comment: Thank you so much, Hans Kilian! I removed the Else block and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `else` block which has a `return` so your loop will not work.

But you can just use:

```cs
// bit more array items to test
var nums = new[] { 2, 7, 11, 0, 15, 2, 9 };
int target = 9;

// Your second test case
// var nums = new[] { 3, 2, 4 };
// int target = 6;

var results = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    var currI = nums[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < nums.Length; x++)
    {
        var currX = nums[x];
        var sum = currI + currX;

        // just with the correct sum and it is not already in the result
        if (sum == target && i != x && !results.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            results[i] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in

```
0, 1
1, 5
3, 6
```

If you just need to know the first combination do a `.FirstOrDefault()`

Working full example can be found here: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gRNoOe)

Comment: Thank you, Martin! I removed the Else block. My code only gets the first answer, but I will try and change it so it can display the other results.

Answer (score 0):

you can semplify your code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var nums = new[] { 2, 7, 11, 0, 15, 2, 9 };
        int target = 9;

        for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            for (var x = i; x < nums.Length; x++)
                if (nums[i] + nums[x] == target)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}, {x}");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jak! Is it preferred to have two For loops nested like this instead of what I have with k= i+1 inside of an If statement?

Comment: @Evangeline Drink: There are no better or worse ways if it work fine. The only considerations I could make are: The fewer tests there are, the faster the code is. The code is interesting when it reflects algorithms known as simple combinations in this case. Not last use less memory as possible.

Comment: @Evangeline Drink: Your program will also need 2 nested for loops otherwise, as it is written now, you will always check only one value with only the next one and not all the others.

Comment: Thanks again! I looked up the simple combinations algorithm and it makes sense as to why you can use two For loops for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int[] TwoSumBruteForce(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        //Declarations
        int arrayLength = nums.Length;

        //Validations
        if (nums == null || arrayLength < 2)
        {
            return Array.Empty<int>();
        }

        //Logic
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayLength; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                    return new int[] { i, j };
            }
        }
        return Array.Empty<int>();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).